# Gmail and others recognize my emails as spam

Tags: email, gmail, spam-prevention, vps

I have mail set up on VPS. Everything checked 10x. Dns entries, testers, open blacklists etc. etc. and all my messages are sent to spam :(
Why?
Here are the results of online tests - it's look fine 
http://www.isnotspam.com/newlatestreport.php?email=ins-eop043g0%40isnotspam.com

https://www.mail-tester.com/test-3yrkb

RBL >    http://www.anti-abuse.org/multi-rbl-check-results/?host=airgun.pl

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're on a VPS. Your source (address vs. host name) cannot be verified. So because of your, or your service providers filtering policy. They're dropped into your SPAM folder -- Privacy comes at a cost. :)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Reasons that leads your mail into spam box:
1. If other people are deleting your mails/not replying or simply no engagement between two.
2. Your Ip is marked spam( But as you mentioned that you are on VPS, and @somebody answered, your source can't be verified)
3. You need to check are you using some words in title/content that may be looks spam.